# NSLog/OSLog intermittently showing up in console

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, logging

I've noticed that my NSLog (and I've also tried it with os_log) statements are not showing up consistently in the console application.

Here's some code that runs when my app starts up.

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        NSLog("xyz didFinishLaunchingWithOptions")
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        NSLog("xyz FirebaseApp.configure() done")
        let db = FirestoreDelegate.db()
        let now = Date()
        NSLog("xyz about to write")
        db.collection("atest").document(DateUtils.formatTimestampGMT(now)).setData(["ts": now, "note":"delegate startup"]) {
            err in
            if let err = err {
                NSLog ("xyz error ats \(err)")
                return
            }
            NSLog("xyz wrote to ats \(DateUtils.formatTimestampGMT(now))")
        }
        NSLog("xyz after write")
        ... extraneous code removed
}
```

When I run, sometimes I see "xyz didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" and "wrote to ats", but none of the other log statements. Sometimes I see them all, but it's pretty inconsistent. Are they getting filtered or optimized out somehow?

I'm not debugging through xcode, I'm just running the app on my phone and viewing the logs through the console app on my computer.

Comment: I experienced that too when OSLog first came out (2 years ago). I haven't tried it much since. I'm not sure if it's just because it's connected to the console or even if you log it to the iOS and retrieve it through sysdiagnose it be the same.

Comment: I ended up just appending log statements to a file and was able to figure out my issue that way. Now I don't feel like I can't trust the built in logging.

Comment: Can you share your code of how you wrote the oslog to a file?

Comment: @Honey I didn't redirect the logs to a file. I created a FileWriter class that writes to a file and called that instead of the log functions. I ripped it out once I figured out my issue. I'll post it below as an answer.

Comment: I wonder if this is just during launch. I’ve often had trouble with that.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to figure out some issues when the app was launched in background mode, which is why i could run with the debugger attached.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't figure out why the logging is inconsistent. Instead I created a custom logger that writes to a file.

```swift
public class FileWriter {
    static func getTs() -> String {
        let timestampFormat = DateFormatter()
        timestampFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        return timestampFormat.string(from: Date())
    }

    static func write(_ text: String) {
        do {
            let dir: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last! as URL
            let url = dir.appendingPathComponent("log.txt")
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
                FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: url.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
            }
            let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: url)

            let line = "\(getTs()) \(text)\n"
            let data = line.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.write(data)

            fileHandle.closeFile()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print ("error \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

To read the file, I added the following keys to my Info.plist "UIFileSharingEnabled"
, "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" and then I could open the file on my phone with the Files app.

Comment: If you're going down this path, then any reason you didn't use CocoaLumberJack?

Comment: I’ve never heard of it. Didn’t really want to add a dependency.

Comment: fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile Is clever but OutputStream is a much better way to append to a file.

Comment: Take a look at this [presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/parrots/logging-in-production) by Parrots. It gives a nice overview of its benefits